# ExpressJS: Subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, routes, subdomain

In my app, I am creating multiple users like `user1,user2...` and want to assign subdomain for each user like `user1.xyz.com,user2.xyz.com ...` Following are the requirements for the app:

1) Create these subdomains dynamically as the user is registered with the   app

2) `GET user1.xyz.com` should call a route like `/user1/home`

I have seen a npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain but looks like it will work only for static subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a package which fulfills the requirement:

https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/subdomain.

```
app.use(subdomain({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));

app.get('/subdomain/:name', Controller});    //GETs user1.localhost and user1 can be used as parameter using req.params.name
```

Eg.

```
app.get('/subdomain/:name',function(req,res){
  var name = req.params.name;
  res.send(name);
});
```